# How I can avoid error when running an electron project created on Mac in a Windows?

Tags: node.js, electron

The problem is that I started to learn electron on my Mac, but when I tried to show the project on my friend's computer (which uses Windows) I got the following error in the CMD:

```
"electron" is not recognized as an internal or external command,
program or executable batch file.
```

The only thing that can be used was to delete the electron folder in node_modules and then reinstalled and it worked. But my question is if there is a way to avoid this and so I could open my project on Mac, Windows or Linux whitout deliting and reinstalling electron every time.

Comment: Don't commit the `node_modules` folder as part of the repository, and when you clone the repo, just run `npm install` as the first step. That's pretty typical with Node.js projects in general.

Comment: I think the best way is packaging your app with `electron-builder` so you can run your app on other machines and operating system